# Are logical OR and comma operators equivalent?

Tags: c++, operators, comma-operator

Today I found a syntax thing I had never seen before. Are `||` and `,` the same?

```
bool f() {

    cout << "f";
    return true;
}

bool g() {

    cout << "g";
    return true;
}

int main() {


    if(f(),g())
    {
        cout<<"OK with ,";
    }

    cout<<endl;

    if(f()||g())
    {

        cout<<"OK with ||";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

From the output of this program, it seems so:

```
fgOK with ,
fOK with ||
```

Are they the same exact thing or are there any little differences?

Comment: No, they're different operators. In fact, your output is wrong per the standard.

Comment: This is a bit like asking whether + and * are the same because 2+2 and 2*2 give the same result.

Comment: -1, your code does not reproduce your alleged output (unless your compiler is badly broken). And no, they are not the same.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth except the result is not the same. Originally, it was using `&&` instead of `||`, so the result would have been the same. So it is more like asking whether `+` and `*` are the same because `3+3` and `3*3` give the same result :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Comma Operator work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work)

Answer (score 4):

`f(),g()` means evaluate `f()` then evaluate `g()` and return `g()` since your `g()` returns `true` it is that what is returned to `if`

So, no, the operators are totally different.

You can see the difference if you modify your function to return `false` from `g()`. The condition `f()||g()` will still evaluate to `true` while `f(),g()` will return `false`.

Answer (score 3):

This (comma operator)

```
if(f(),g())
```

will evaluate both `f()` and `g()` and return the value of the second operand `g()`

The logical OR operator

```
if(f()||g())
```

will not evaluate `g()` if `f()` evaluates to true. This is known as [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) - if f() returns true, then the logical OR condition is already satisfied - hence there is no point evaluating `g()`.

So they are **NOT** the same at all even though under certain conditions you may see the same overall behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

They are completely different operators that serve completely different purposes.

The main difference is that:

- The `,` operator (unless overloaded) will evaluate all of its arguments and return the last one, no matter what.
- The `||` operator will evaluate all the arguments until it reaches the first `true`ish value and will not evaluate the rest.

This is also the reason why the output, you are claiming to receive, [is wrong](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8515a5b649d54cb7).

Answer (score 2):

- **||** is the logical OR operator and by standard it follows [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (i.e. it won't evaluate the second operand if the first already suffices to determine the entire logical expression)
- **,** is the comma operator that evaluates both but just return the value of the second operand.

By the way you should be seeing something like:

```
fgOK with ,
fOK with ||
```

the reason why you're not seeing it might be because you're using a compiler that doesn't strictly follow the standards (I suspect MSVC..)

http://ideone.com/8dSFiY